# Divergent intuition for a question in Fraleigh's Intro to Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently reading *A First Course in Abstract Algebra* by John. B. Fraleigh, 7th edition.

In the chapter 0' exercises, there is this question:

> Let $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{3, 4, 5\}$. Illustrate, using A and B, why we consider 2 + 3 = 5. Use similar reasoning with sets of your own choice to decide  what you would consider to be the value of i. $3 + \aleph_0$ and ii. $\aleph_0 + \aleph_0$.

In the solution manual, Fraleigh says that $3 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$ since we simply create a set $A = \{-2, -1, 0\}$ with $|A| = 3$ and extend $B = \mathbb{Z}^+$ to obtain $C = \{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3,...\}$ with $|C| = \aleph_0$ and so $3 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$.

However, I had a different intuition for his question, one that might only work on $\mathbb{Z}$. We define $A$ and $B$ the same way but we interpret $A$ as a set containing the index offset inside $B$. This example $2+3=5$ would then turn into, starting from the element $3$ inside $B$, move $2$ indexes to obtain the result of $2+3$, thus giving $5$.

Using this intuition, we define $3 + \aleph_0$ as moving three indexes to the right inside the set of cardinalities and $3 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_3$.

My question is then: is this intuition wrong? If so, what is the problem with it? If not, where can I learn more?

N.b.: I know that $2+5$ is not in $B$ but the question's answer doesn't really deal with this problem too.

Comment: This intuition is wrong. I'm not sure exactly what it means to change the "index offset" inside a set. What is this, and what happens when you change this? Does this correspond to adding the cardinalities in any meaningful way? How does this give you $\aleph_{3}$ from $3+\aleph_{0}$?

Comment: Well, if we have $B=\{3.4.5\}$, $2+3$ means we move from the index of $3$ in $B$ to the element two indexes higher, so $3$ is the element at the first index, $4$ at the second index, $5$ at the third index. So if we're moving two indexes up from the first one, we end up at the element on the third index which is $5$. What I mean by the set of cardinality is $\{\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2, ...\}$. I hope it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @DatCorno In order to help us understand it, could you apply your intuition to $\{3, 6, 7\}$ and $\{\text{cow}, \text{chicken}\}$ instead?

Comment: @MorganRodgers this pretty much answers my question thanks, I had forgotten that sets are not ordered, we just write them ordered by convenience.

Comment: If I might still provide some kind of analogy to my question, imagine $B$ as a table with three columns. In the first column is written the number 3. In the second column is written the number 4. In the third column is written the number 5. Saying 2+3 means that, starting from the column containing the number 3, we move two columns to the right and obtain 5.

Comment: What if your three columns contain 3, 4, and 7. By your reasoning, $2+3$ should be $7.$

Answer (score 0):

ii.  $\aleph_0 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$.

You "intuition" is apparently confusing.
Instead of indexes, think in terms of bijections.